# Something Wrong With elementary appcenter

Tags: release-loki, elementary-website, appcenter

Today i've noticed my appcenter is not installing removing or cheching for updates. When i try to install something the bar just shows "starting" and then nothing happens.I tried to reinstall it but its still the same. I dont want to use other package managers since appcenter is more integrated and simple please help.I also tried to remove ppas related with elementary and write sudo apt-get update- upgrade but still no chance

Answer (score 0):

Would it be worth a try to open the terminal and type

```
sudo apt update
```

Then reboot the machine and see if that works?

Comment: I tried that dozens of time. I think the problem related with installing other package managers but synaptic.

Comment: I'm not sure what steps you have taken to get to this stage. Some apps in the app centre don't seem to be compatible which is why you are receiving the "starting" followed by the slider moving back to the left.

What was the reason for you removing the ppas related to elementary?